# Echo value into hidden field?

Tags: php, forms, echo, hidden-field

I am trying to find out and track what browser and if a proxy is being used when I receive form submissions. I have the following code below:

```
<?php

$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ip_address = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}

?>
```

For example I tried the below but it does not work. It is not submitting any data with my form.

What am I doing wrong?

```
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="browser" value="' . $browser . '" />' );
```

Comment: you cannot embed php code inside php strings like that and expect it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="browser" value="'.$browser.'">'
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

- You are not referencing the variable with a `$`
- You need to correctly escape the variable value from the string

Try [**printf**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
printf('<input type="hidden" name="browser" value="%s">', $browser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are combining echo and print (which both do the same) into one call. For another thing, you haven't closed the input element HTML (notice the final greater than sign I've added):

`echo ('<input type="hidden" name="browser" value="' . $browser . '" />' );`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
echo ("<input type='hidden' name='browser' value='".$browser."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="browser" value="'.$browser.'">');
```

Try with `this ->  value="'.$browser.'"`  something like that